# Авторизация на внешнем ресурсе через PHP

Tags: php, авторизация

Есть внешний сайт с формой авторизации (post).
Можно ли с помощью PHP-файла на другом ресурсе авторизироваться на внешнем ресурсе?

Comment: я ничего не понял

Comment: Ну в теории можно, `CURL` вам в помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Можно! Для этого вам следует использовать библиотеку CURL. С её помощью вы сможете полностью эмитировать действия пользователя на каком либо сайте. Об этом рассказано в [этом видеокурсе](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oVdwiuqeOt0&index=4&list=PLjvEG-kS6RG3E9Ijpb3s_hnJDEuYHQFBr).